# popover tableview shows then disappears

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

On a button click I am showing a popover view which is a tableview.

Everything seems to work and the view shows but then disappears in less than a second.

The tableview contains a list of strings and I set the tablecell to be show checkmark.

I notice that table shows all items checked in the split second it is displayed

Anyone knows what I am missing.

Thanks

Hassan

Code to show the popover

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"WholesalersList"]){
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        WholesalersViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
        vc.wholesalers = [appDelegate.wholesalers mutableCopy];
        if ([segue isKindOfClass:[UIStoryboardPopoverSegue class]]){
            self.wholesalersPopoverController = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue popoverController];
            [self.wholesalersPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(334, 334)];
            //[self.wholesalersPopoverController setDelegate:self];
        }
    }
}
```

Code in the popover tableview

```
#pragma mark Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)theTableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if ([self.wholesalers count] == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return [self.wholesalers count];
    }
}

#pragma mark Table view delegate
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([self.wholesalers count] == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    else {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"WholesalerCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        // Configure the cell.
        Wholesaler *ws = (Wholesaler *)[self.wholesalers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text = ws.name;

        return cell;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 44;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;      // The table view should not be re-orderable.
}
```

Comment: Without code, how do we help you ?

Comment: updated question with code.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you soryngod for making the code look better

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/Popovers.html

Answer (score 0):

Are calling the dismissPopover:Animated anywhere in the code like mistakenly in the IBAction method for the button or you dont have an IBAction method?

Comment: Echorus I was. Very well spotted! Thank you.  I had this code in my IBAction

Comment: if (self.wholesalersPopoverController == nil){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"WholesalersList" sender:self];
    }
    else{
        [self.wholesalersPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        self.wholesalersPopoverController = nil;
    }    

I don't still know why the else part is executing.  And it is because when I commented it out it works.

Thanks for spotting that
H